# Gson library in Android Studio

Tags: android, gson

Can someone give me  step by step guide to add the Gson library to an Android project?

I tried the `JSON` built-in library but that seems to be a bit tedious right now. I saw a couple of examples based on Gson, and that seems really easy.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Add following dependency to `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
```

Or download the JAR file [from Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) by clicking a release and finding the .jar file.

Replace 2.8.7 with the latest version from Maven.

Visit the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/google/gson) for documentation and more.

Comment: Do i need to download the jar file,or should i just add compile 'com.XX??

Comment: It didn't owrked immediatley after adding in dependencies and trying to build my app. I had restarted my android studio and tried to rebuild it. It worked  :)

Comment: @SillySam: Your edit should have been a new answer since it completely rewrites this answer.

Comment: @JagadishDharanikota I noticed this as well. I think you can fix without restarting by using File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 33):

Read **[Google-gson](https://github.com/google/gson)**

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into
> their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON
> string to an equivalent Java object.

Add the following line to your ***MODULE LEVEL*** **`build.gradle`** configuration:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8' // Old 2.8.6
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use **gradle dependencies** to get the **Gson** in your project. Your application  **build.gradle** should look like this-

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to use it with [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library, I suggest you to use Square's gson library as:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Comment: Any specific reasons for Squares Gson being better than Googles Gson?

Answer (score 2):

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.5</version> 
</dependency>
```

[Gson jar](https://maven-badges.herokuapp.com/maven-central/com.google.code.gson/gson) downloads are available from Maven Central.

Comment: Now i know mate, 3 years ago this wasn't relevant enough to know :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of adding JAR to your project by yourself, just add dependency in build.gradle (Module lavel). **ALSO** always try to use the upgraded version, as of now is

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

As every incremental version has some bugs fixes or up-gradations as mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: i know ,but wasn't aware of it 3 years back :)

Comment: @Venky ... i posted this answer for SO's who are still in ambiguity... :)