# Importing GSON using gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import GSON into my project using gradle in android studio. I have used instructions found on [google'sGitHub](https://github.com/google/gson) and several stack overflow pages, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048731/gson-library-in-android-studio). However when I go to import into my file using the line

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

I still get the following error

> Error:(5, 23) error: package com.google.gson does not exist

example from my app's build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

and my settings.gradle

```
include 'gson:2.7'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10):

Open your project. Go to **File -> Project Structure...**
Click on **app** in the **Modules** section and switch to the **Dependencies** tab. Click on the plus icon in the top right corner and select **Library dependency**. Select the entry for the GSON library from the list and hit OK twice. (Note: the search bar didn't work for me)

Then you are able to use the library just like you described in your question:
`import com.google.gson.Gson;`

Note that after adding the library your project will do a gradle sync which may take a couple of minutes.

Comment: Mine doesn't appear in the Module list for com.google.* query...

Comment: @MichaelPaccione try selecting main folder inside your project folder.

also try to click on new library button next to "add selected"  and add com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7 as the path of the library to add

Comment: @jemand771 why doesnt it work by simply adding it to build.gradle

Comment: @KaranAhuja I haven't worked with android studio and/or gradle in a while, so this is just a guess: Sounds like you need to install the library beofre you can import/use it. Though as I've said, I don't really know anymore

Comment: @jemand771 sure cool.
I think if i add it to build.gradle , the library is auto installed , barring this one.
i do not know reason for why gson is not installed just by adding it as dependency in build.gradle.
for now i have been able to fix it based on the answers here - adding it manually in idea.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency should be imported properly after syncing your project.
Try selecting *Sync Project with Gradle Files* in the upper right corner of Android Studio (referring to the default layout of Bumblebee).