# Unable to import Gson in gradle file

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm trying without success to import this `import com.google.gson.Gson` in one gradle file I've created just to manage some tasks. I'm able to import this Gson in other parts of the app, it is only here where I'm having issues.

In my gradle.app I have

[image]

I also tried an answer from [Importing GSON using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308165/importing-gson-using-gradle), but when I open the menu nothing appears.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: did you just set up the gradle file? are there other things in that file that are correctly importing? if you just set up the gradle file make sure it's in your settings.gradle file

Comment: @Rafa, i´m not sure what you mean. I just created a new .gradle file and add it the code. The task works without the json part. Do you have some documentation I could check ?

Comment: within your project you should have a settings.gradle file. This is the list of gradle files that the project is going to pick up. If you added a gradle.build file in your project but didn't add it into the settings.gradle file, it won't run any tasks for it. I think this might be the best documentation for what I'm talking about. https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_applications_multi_project.html#review_the_project_files

I'm just covering some of the bases, but if you're not sure, double check that :)