# Why can't I parse the JSON?

Tags: android, json

I am sorry for I am a beginner.

I try to put the value into string name[], int age [], int hand[],
but all the value is null.

I don't know which part have problem. Since i learn this from youtube.

I just want to store the data to array.

Thank you

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {
String oName[] = new String []; 
int oAge [] = new int [];
int oHand [] = new int [];

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground (String... values) { 
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = ""; //Get json?
        String line;
        try {
            URL ua = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/r5kim"); //json address
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ua.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            is.close();
           JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result); //get json
           JSONArray op = jo.getJSONArray("opponents"); //json array?? parse??
            for(int i = 0; i < op.length(); i++) {
                oName[i] = op.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"); //Get null
                oAge[i] = op.getJSONObject(i).getInt("age"); //Get null
                oHand[i] = op.getJSONObject(i).getInt("hand"); //Get null
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) { //exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) { //exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) { //exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Post the logs as well

Comment: Also, try to log 'result' string , then 'jo' and 'op' . See what you get in result.

Comment: after above action, i try to get the value from oName array to the textview, then the app get stopping.
btw I will try log the string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the json string it is hard to determinate what you are doing wrong.

The best advice I can give you is to check out [gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) which is the most common json parser on Android (there are obv more, this is the one I use). [how to add reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048731/gson-library-in-android-studio).

Watching videos, searching on google and also here on SO you will find thousands of "how to use gson posts", but anyway I will give you the fastest "how to" for it.

**1. Assume you have a string like this:**

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Little Mouse"
}
```

**2. Create an object matching the one passed by json string**

```
public class MyObject{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    //getters and setters
}
```

**3. Now initialize gson and parse the string to the desired object**

```
//Initialize Gson object with GsonBuilder (you can customize it, you will learn)
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

//parse your string using an object matching your output
MyObject myObject = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, MyObject.class);
```

It is pretty simple, but if you need help, ask freely

**Post scriptum:**

*you can obiouvsly parse any kind of class, with also custom parameters and nested classes. You just have to create a model class with the parameters you need written with the same name (or you can explicit the desired name) and with the same property type (int, string, ...)*

This is your model:

```
public class myJsonModel{

    private List<Opponent> opponents;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Opponent{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String hand;
    //getters and setters
}
```

So your result should be

```
myJsonModel myObject = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, myJsonModel.class);
```

Comment: ok, thanks i would understand the gson, 
btw i have post the url of json

Comment: @SiuMingLau added your specific case in answer